# Center of Mass with two functions

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to go about this problem. I can do problems with single variables but I can not solve this one. I think I would need to subtract the functions from one another but I am not sure which should be subtracted from which. If anyone can help with tips or solutions it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The first step is finding the area bounded by the curves (since that is used in the denominator of the centroid calculations), so it is valuable to have a knowledge of the functions or a graph (or sketch of a graph).  On the given interval, $ \ \sin x < \cos x \ . $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for Centroid

$$f\left(x\right) = 9\cos \left(x\right) ; g\left(x\right) = 9\sin \left(x\right)$$

$$\bar x =\dfrac{ ∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}} x\left(f\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right) dx}{∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}} \left(f\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right)dx}$$

$$\bar y= \dfrac{ ∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}} \frac{\left(f\left(x\right)+g\left(x\right)\right)}{2}\left(f\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right) dx}{∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}}\left(f\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right)dx}$$

To further elaborate:

Denominator = $$9∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}}\left(\cos \left(x\right) -\sin \left(x\right)\right) dx = 9.\left(2\right).\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-9 = 9.\sqrt{2}-9$$

Numerator for $$\bar x = 9∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}}\left(x\cos \left(x\right) -x\sin \left(x\right)\right) dx$$

Evaluate the integral by integration by parts.  I will show the example for one of them:

$$∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}}x\cos \left(x\right)dx $$

Put u = x, dv = cos(x)dx => du = dx and v = sin(x)

$$∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}} udv = uv -∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}}vdu = \left[x\sin \left(x\right) +\cos \left(x\right)\right] |\frac{π}{4},0$$

Similarly Put Put u = x, dv = sinxdx => du = dx and v = -cos(x)
$$∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}} udv = uv -∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}}vdu = \left[-x\cos \left(x\right) +\sin \left(x\right)\right] |\frac{π}{4},0$$
Thus the numerator $$= 9*\left[x\sin \left(x\right) +\cos \left(x\right) - \left[-x\cos \left(x\right) +\sin \left(x\right)\right]\right]= x\left(\sin \left(x\right) + \cos \left(x\right)\right) + \cos \left(x\right) - \sin \left(x\right) = 9\left(\frac{π}{4}.\sqrt{2}-1\right)$$

$$\bar x = \dfrac{9\frac{π}{4}\sqrt{2} -9}{9\sqrt{2}-9}$$

For the $\bar y$
Numerator = 
$$∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}} \frac{81}{2} \left[\cos \left(x\right) - \sin \left(x\right)\right]\left[\cos \left(x\right) + \sin \left(x\right)\right]$$

$$∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}} \frac{81}{2}\left[\cos ^{2}\left(x\right) - \sin ^{2}\left(x\right)\right] $$
$$∫_0^{\frac{{π}}{4}} \frac{81}{2}\cos \left(2x\right) = \frac{81}{2} \frac{\sin \left(2x\right)}{2}$$
$$\bar y =\frac{81}{4}.1$$

$$\bar y = \frac{81}{4}$$

Centroid = $$\left(\bar x, \bar y\right) = \left(\dfrac{9\frac{π}{4}\sqrt{2}-9}{9\sqrt{2}-9}, {\frac{81}{4\left(9\sqrt{2}-9\right)}}\right)$$

Thanks

Satish

Comment: This answer is incorrect according to my homework website. Thank you for the help I am going to keep working at it. If you come up with anything else any help is still great!

Comment: @user124786, What is the correct answer, if you don't mind

Comment: @user124786, Does it seem correct wit an edit?

Comment: Yes! Your edit was correct! thank you so much!

Comment: I think I just did. Did it not work?

Comment: You are welcome,it did work